# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am following a [Spring Data MVC tutorial](http://www.programming-free.com/2014/07/spring-data-rest-with-angularjs-crud.html).

But it is described there as a `Java application`. I need it as a `Server application`.

So in `Spring Tool Suite` I created a `Spring MVC Project`. 
It worked fine.

**Problem:** After I have added two files to the project I get the issue:

```
 StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 29 more
```

Task.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="task_list")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="task_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="task_name")
    private String taskName;

    @Column(name="task_description")
    private String taskDescription;

    @Column(name="task_priority")
    private String taskPriority;

    @Column(name="task_status")
    private String taskStatus;

    @Column(name="task_archived")
    private int taskArchived = 0;

    public int getTaskId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setTaskId(int taskId) {
        this.id = taskId;
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    public String getTaskDescription() {
        return taskDescription;
    }

    public void setTaskDescription(String taskDescription) {
        this.taskDescription = taskDescription;
    }

    public String getTaskPriority() {
        return taskPriority;
    }

    public void setTaskPriority(String taskPriority) {
        this.taskPriority = taskPriority;
    }

    public String getTaskStatus() {
        return taskStatus;
    }

    public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus) {
        this.taskStatus = taskStatus;
    }

    public int isTaskArchived() {
        return taskArchived;
    }

    public void setTaskArchived(int taskArchived) {
        this.taskArchived = taskArchived;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task [id=" + id + ", taskName=" + taskName
                + ", taskDescription=" + taskDescription + ", taskPriority="
                + taskPriority + ",taskStatus=" + taskStatus + "]";
    }
```

TaskRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Integer> {

    List<Task> findByTaskArchived(@Param("archivedfalse") int taskArchivedFalse);
    List<Task> findByTaskStatus(@Param("status") String taskStatus);

}
```

I have not done any changes to my controller.

controller:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.springmvcproject" />

</beans:beans>
```

**Question:** What could I have done wrong?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` means you are missing a jar file in your classpath. In this case, you're missing the `spring-beans-XXX.jar` file.